# rtk query acting one step behind in setting the states

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query, inversifyjs

im using dependency injection in my next.js project by the aidf of inversify librarby
this is the rtk api

```
import { ErrorResponseDto, IResponseDto } from "@/domain/dto";
import baseApi from "../baseApi";
import { SuccessLoginResponseDto } from "@/application/interfaces/handlers/auth";
import { BrandReq } from "@/application/interfaces/handlers/brands";


const brandApi = baseApi.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    addBrand: builder.mutation<void, BrandReq>({
      query: (newBrand) => ({
        url: "brand", 
        method: "POST",
        body: newBrand,
      }),
    }),
  }),
});

export const {  addBrand } = brandApi.endpoints;

export default brandApi;
```

this is my slice

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { BrandState } from "@/domain/entity/brand-entities";
import { addBrand } from "@/infrastructure/redux/apis/brand";
import container from "../../../../../ioc.config";
import { BRANDS_HANDLERS_TYPES } from "@/application/types/handlers/brands";
import type { BrandsHandlersImpl } from "@/application/interfaces/handlers/brands";
import { ErrorResponseDto, IResponseDto } from "@/domain/dto";

const initialState: BrandState = {
  brandList: [],
  loading: false,
  error: null,
};

const brandSlice = createSlice({
  name: "brand",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addMatcher(addBrand.matchPending, (state) => {
      const { pending } = container.get<BrandsHandlersImpl>(BRANDS_HANDLERS_TYPES.BrandsHandlersImp);
      pending(state);
    });
    builder.addMatcher<PayloadAction<IResponseDto<void>>>(addBrand.matchFulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
      const { success } = container.get<BrandsHandlersImpl>(BRANDS_HANDLERS_TYPES.BrandsHandlersImp);
      success(state, payload);
    });
    builder.addMatcher<PayloadAction<IResponseDto<ErrorResponseDto>>>(addBrand.matchRejected, (state, { payload }) => {
      const { reject } = container.get<BrandsHandlersImpl>(BRANDS_HANDLERS_TYPES.BrandsHandlersImp);
      
      reject(state, payload);
    });
  },
});


export default brandSlice.reducer;
```

and these are my handlers

```
@injectable()
export class BrandsHandlers implements BrandsHandlersImpl {
  constructor(
    @inject(STATE_MANAGER_TYPES.PrimaryStateManagerImpl)
    private primaryStateManager: PrimaryStateManagerImpl
  ) {}

  async addBrand(newBrand: BrandReq) {
    return await this.primaryStateManager.setState<BrandReq, IResponseDto<void> | ErrorResponseDto>(
      "addBrand",
      newBrand
    );
  }
  async success(state: BrandState, payload: IResponseDto<void>) {
    // console.log(payload);
    state.loading = false;
    state.error = null;
  }

  async pending(state: BrandState) {
    state.loading = true;
    state.error = null;
  }

   async reject(state: BrandState, payload: IResponseDto<ErrorResponseDto>) {
    // console.log(payload.status);
    
    state.error = payload.status?.toString();
    state.loading = false;
  }
}
```

the scenario is wheen im requesting in the componenent , when i log the states in thsese files , i see the states have been chnaged
but the problem is when i try to access the states from compoenets, i see that altough the ajax reuests are doing welll , but i cant access them from appSelector

```
  const { error, loading , brandList :brandlist } = useAppSelector((state) => state.brandState);

  const submit = async (data: FormValues) => {
    await brandService.addBrand({ name: data.name });
    console.log(error);
}
```

i cant access error(and also any other  redux states) immidately , its null for first time , the correct value represents after first try , but in first try these are one step behind
the funny thing about these is when i return these staes into th tsx i can see the result , but i dodnt have access them from function scope ,